# Quartz.NET - How to determine the trigger from IJobExecutionContext

Tags: quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET and users can trigger jobs manually, or they run on a schedule. Is there a way from the IJobExecutionContext object to tell if it was manually triggered?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I managed to determine if the jobs were manually triggered by using the following property - context.Trigger.Key.Name.StartsWith("MT")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually triggered job has trigger name starting with "MT_". See the job execution context for trigger information.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that its specifically the key Name property, not the full key value which includes a generated group name

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the IJobExecutionContext.Trigger(ITrigger).Description.

Or something on the IJobExecutionContext.Trigger.

That would seem to be the place to look differences in the firing mechanism.